# Save ListView Scroll Position in the Same Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a long `ListView` with edittext that the user can scroll in a Fragment.When the user stops scrolling and come back to the list in the same fragment,I want the list to be scrolled to the same point that it was previously. 
If the ListView has 20 rows,and the user has entered value on 5th row,after scrolling down and coming back ,the cursor should be positioned on 5th row.

I am using the `ListView` from the `ListFragment` and I have a custom `adapter` which extends `ArrayAdapter` that fills the ListView. I cannot use the onSaveInstanceState and onActivityCreated as I am not leaving the Fragment.

How can I store the `ListView` current position to use it later?

Comment: You want to save the scrolling position when the screen rotates, user exists the app or which scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save state of Fragment having listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810749/how-to-save-state-of-fragment-having-listview)

Comment: Here is a demo. https://github.com/tim-ashton/Android-Fragment-List-Demo

Comment: Hi Catalina,If the ListView has 20 rows,and the user has entered value on 5th row,after scrolling down and coming back ,the cursor should be positioned on 5th row.

Answer (score 0):

When you action triggered, you can get the first visible item position in the list view for the user now by:

```
int position = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Whenever you want to set the scrolling position again later, use the following:

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

You can use `SharedPReferences` to store this location, in case of you want to store it for long time (more than one session).

Note: take care of your stored position, if your list is generic and might be shorter later to avoid `indexOutOfBound` crash.

For more information about how to use `SharedPreferences` visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 0):

Within the ListFragment fragment declare two int variables to hold the scroll position:

```
public static class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

        private int listIndex = -1;
        private int listTop = 0;
```

Then override the onPause() and onResume() to save and restore the `ListView`'s scroll positions as follows:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

   //after setting adapter and your arbitrary codes
      if(listIndex!=-1){
         this.getListView().setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
      }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      try {
        listIndex = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = getListView().getChildAt(0);
        listTop = (v != null) ? v.getTop() : 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Wish to diminish the pains!! :blush: